# Using filter in makefile to run other make targets

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to simplify my makefile by allowing a target with a filter (%) to capture when I want other targets to have expanded actions

An example of this would be

```
1-check: 
  echo "1"

2-check:
  echo "2"

run-check: 
  1-check-all 2-check-all

%-all: 
  echo $*
```

This is able to print the 2 targets names as 1-check and 2-check and I was expecting that if I remove the echo in %-all it would run the captured target

What I would expect when I call 1-check-all is that the modified %-all - seen below - it would invoke the method

```
%-all: 
  $*
```

Would have "1-check" as the value of $* and it would then run that target and I would see "echo 1" executed.

I am new to makefiles and haven't been able to find an example doing something similar to this.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of problems. This:

```
%-all: 
    $*
```

does not appear in your makefile. The nearest thing to it is this:

```
%-all: 
    echo $*
```

But neither of these will invoke another rule. To get the effect I think you want, you must list `%` as a *prerequisite* of the rule:

```
%-all: %
    echo $*
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I updated the question to be more clear. The final version of %-all target would call the target % captures. So when calling 1-check-all %-check should have 1-check as the value of $*. Your suggestion of listing % as a prerequisite ends up failing with  "mixed implicit and static pattern rules".

Comment: @IMac, you seem not to be grasping that the recipe associated with a rule consists of *shell commands*, not targets to build.  Perhaps you also are not appreciating that `make` rules are not well characterized as functions that can be "called".

Comment: @IMac: I cannot reproduce your error; this solution works perfectly for me, and there is no static pattern rule in it.